# Парсинг долготы/широты/адреса предприятий из атласа промышленности минпромторга

Tags: парсер, карты, яндекс-карты

Коллеги, привет!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли идеи, как можно спарить
Долготу/Широту/Адреса промышленных объектов?
https://gisp.gov.ru/atlas/map/public

Comment: там данные подтягиваются для видимой области карты. попробуйте ручками отправить запрос указав широту/долготу такую, чтобы вся РФ влезала и масштаб карты максимальный. а вдруг прокатит.

Comment: судя по тому, что ответ пришел 27мбайт размером, то прокатывает

Comment: Спасибо! а что за запрос вы отправили и каким образом?)

Comment: ф12 жмите, вкладку сеть смотрите на xhr запросы. в ФФ по крайней мере можно кликнуть "Изменить и отправить снова". меняете координаты и отправляете снова. Но надо изучать, что именно там грузится. возможно придется сводить с нескольких запросов в одну кучу. В отправленном мною были id объектов и координаты полигонов для отрисовки. подписей не было, почему-то. Хотя я выборочно смотрел пару точек.